# Alignment Issues with bootstrap

Tags: c#, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to horizontally align my view form page but cannot figure out a way. Here is a snapshot of the page. Please help. For example, the city and the city name are not aligned. How can I do that ?

[For example, the city and the city name are not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYVZY.png)

```
<div class="well well-sm">
            <h4>Contact Information</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MailingAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 " })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MailingAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.MailingAddress) } })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Can you please include the code?

Comment: If you override any styles in CSS, please include that as well.

Comment: I did not override any CSS styles. Here is my code :

Comment: Do you want to display the text or should this be editable?  You are styling it with a form-control, which is typically used on an input form.

Comment: Can you put your code on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I just want to display the text. It should not be editable. Just for viewing. So how should I change the input form ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for [horizontal forms](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-horizontal) to align properly you have to surround any `.form-group`s with a `.form-horizontal`. For example:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <p class="form-control-static">email@example.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's a [runnable example](https://www.bootply.com/YUYlUnJSXH).

EDIT:

You also need to make sure your content is wrapped in a tag with the `form-control-static` class. The default behavior of `@Html.DisplayFor` will just output text, making the HTML attributes you tried to apply useless.

Comment: It should also be noted that the DisplayFor literally only renders text, and not an element.  Therefore, you can not add a class to it in that fashion.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky the output of DisplayFor depends on whether or not they have a DisplayTemplate defined. But you are correct, if they don't have a DisplayTemplate then it will not align correctly. I will update the answer.